# How can I add a "group" of rows and increment their "group id" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table *my_table* with primary key *id* set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
id  group_id  data_column
1   1         'data_1a'
2   2         'data_2a'
3   2         'data_2b'
```

I am stuck trying to build a query that will take an array of data, say ['data_3a', 'data_3b'], and appropriately increment the *group_id* to yield:

```
id  group_id  data_column
1   1         'data_1a'
2   2         'data_2a'
3   2         'data_2b'
4   3         'data_3a'
5   3         'data_3b'
```

I think it would be easy to do using a WITH clause, but this is not supported in MySQL. I am very new to SQL, so **maybe I am organizing my data the wrong way**? (A group is supposed to represent a group of files that were uploaded together via a form. Each row is a single file and the the data column stores its path).

The "Psuedo SQL" code I had in mind was:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (group_id, data_column)
VALUES ($NEXT_GROUP_ID, 'data_3a'), ($NEXT_GROUP_ID, 'data_3b')
LETTING $NEXT_GROUP_ID = (SELECT MAX(group_id) + 1 FROM my_table)
```

where the made up 'LETTING' clause would only evaluate once at the beginning of the query.

Comment: It appears to me that if you would be able to construct the values for "data_column" from the values of the other fields, "data_column" would be functionally dependent on the other fields, and thus redundant. If it is real data somebody has to enter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather have a seperate table for the groups if a group represents files which belong together, especially when you maybe want to save meta data about this group (like the uploading user, the date etc.). Otherwise (in this case) you would get redundant data (which is bad – most of the time).

Alternatively, MySQL does have something like variables. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html

Comment: Thanks, a separate table for the groups makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a transaction do a select max(group_id)+1, and then do the inserts. Or even by locking the table so others can't change (insert) to it would be possible